# SingleChildScroll view not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I probably misuse the widget. I want to make a card scrollable because it overflows on smaller devices :

[image]

My code is :

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
            builder:(BuildContext context,BoxConstraints viewportConstraints){ 

            return _currentItem == 1 ? FadeTransition(
              opacity: fadeAnimation,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new HotelAdditionnalInfo(),
              ),
```

`HotelAdditionnalInfo()` is a widget with a fixed height (that's why I want to make it scrollable) being :

```dart
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
              blurRadius: 15.0
          ),
        ]
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      height: 300.0,
      child: Stack( ...
```

Adding SingleChildScrollView doesn't seem to change anything, there is still this yellow overflow :/

Comment: post the whole widget tree (including `MaterialApp` and  `Scaffold`)

Comment: I'd be veeery long

Comment: `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(64, (i) => Text('#$i', textScaleFactor: 2,)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }` - does it work?

Comment: it works, no yellow overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try wraping your `SingleChildScrollView` into a `Container` and then give that `Container` a height say *300* for example.

```
              Container(
                height:300,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: new HotelAdditionnalInfo(),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it is still the same :/ Are there some restrictions to make the widget work ?

Comment: Actually that should work, can you please show me your code, So that we can find out the real problem for that overflow.

Comment: Well, in addition to the code I posted, I have this tree structure : `Scaffold >Stack>Positionned>BottomExpandableAppBar>Column>LayoutBuilder` where the bottom appbar is this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_bottom_bar

Comment: @user54517 Bro it may sound weird to you but by only having the tree structure code, we cant trace the actual problem, it can only be tracked by the code and not the code structure. Plus one more suggestion try to Replace your `Column` with a `ListView`, that may help, but if not then feel free to ask every doubt.